# Android gridview clear/refresh contents

Tags: android, gridview, refresh

I have a gridview that loads when the app loads.  The user can click on a button which gets other data to load into the gridview.

1. I want to clear the gridview before the other data is loaded. I can't figure this out.
2. I guess fixing #1 will take care of this, but when i DO click on the button to reload the grid, it doesnt refresh the grid.  I know it's loading the data into the grid though, and this is the weird part, there just happens to be a search textview on the screen and when i click on that and the keyboard comes up, the new rows are appended to the existing rows in the grid.  It's the only time the grid is updated.

Comment: If you've got s setupGridview or gridviewSetup or something a method to setup the grid then just recall it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For clear:

just call `clear()` on your adapter, that's how you [clear](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear%28%29) the gridview.

Comment: I do the grid like this `GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));` so, I'm not sure how to call clear.  Can you elaborate (this is my first grid)?  Thanks

Comment: Hi Metallicraft how did you figure it out?  can you help me please? i am in need of that regourously

Comment: @amity Sorry, I just saw your request.  I assume you figured it out, but all I did was instead of creating a new adapter inside "setAdapter" like "gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));", I created a variable as ButtonAdapter like "ButtonAdapter _myAdapter = new ButtonAdapter(this);" and then I was able to do _myAdapter.clear(); anywhere I wanted...

Comment: adapter.clear() is no method..i cant find it with my ImageAdapter.. @Metallicraft

Answer (score 0):

I tried 1. clear(), try 2. notifychange but none of these work for me.

At last, i do a gridView.clear() before setAdapter then got it right,

cheers.